# Augeas error "unexpected LIDENT, expecting UIDENT"

Tags: augeas

I am trying to implement a new lens based on another one. All I have done so far is to copy the lens in `/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist`, changed its filename and the "module" name in the file itself to "xxx".

When I run `augtool` I get this error:

```
Failed to initialize Augeas
error: Syntax error in lens definition
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/xxx.aug:5.7-.10:syntax error, unexpected LIDENT, expecting UIDENT
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/xxx.aug:syntax error
```

Debian Jessie, augtool 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the module name inside the file has to start with a capital letter, so I simply replaced "xxx" with "Xxx".

(As Google returned zero search results for the error message, I hope this will help somebody sometime...)

Comment: That said, if you want to base your lens on another one, you might want to reuse the lens definitions from the first module, e.g. `let Yyy.foo = Xyy.bar`